# Unresponsive UI while using Async & Await

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, asynchronous

I am trying to use `async` and `await` in my coding while I transfer big amounts of data from my *WCF* service to my *WPF* client application. Now it does take about 2-3 minutes to load the data, but now I struggle with my UI that's **unresponsive** for that total time. It's not very user-friendly. Is there a way to get my my UI responsive while the data loads with the coding that I currently have?

```
public pgSysproStock()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SysproStock.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    this.UpdateStockAsync();
}

private async void UpdateStockAsync()
{
    dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = false;

    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var allStock = await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync();

        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = allStock.Select(item =>
                    new AllStock
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        StockCode = item.StockCode,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        ConvFactAltUom = item.ConvFactAltUom,
                        ConvMulDiv = item.ConvMulDiv,
                        ConvFactOthUom = item.ConvFactOthUom,
                        MulDiv = item.MulDiv,
                        Mass = item.Mass,
                        Updated_Supplier = item.Updated_Supplier,
                        CycleCount = item.CycleCount,
                        ProductClass = item.ProductClass.ToString(),
                        UnitCost = item.UnitCost,
                        Discount = item.Discount,
                        Warehouse = item.Warehouse,
                        MinimumStock = item.MinimumStock,
                        MaximumStock = item.MaximumStock,
                        StockForNow = item.StockForNow,
                        CoilWidth = item.CoilWidth,
                        SheetCoilLength = item.SheetCoilLength,
                        MaterialThickness = item.MaterialThickness
                    }).ToArray();

        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advice! :D

Comment: If it takes so long something is wrong.. Why don't you get the data in little blocks instead of loading all the data at the same time ?

Comment: I don't know how wpf / wcf works, but clearly there are two mistakes: 1) you are not awaitng  `UpdateStockAsync()` when you call it, and, 2) you are calling an async method from within a ctor (which makes it impossible to await it, anyhow).

Comment: @DiogoCunha - Thank you for the comment man! ;) I'm loading about 1500 rows of data. I've never loaded one table in different blocks. Can you give me a link or example of how I could do it?

Comment: 1500 rows is not so much as I expected .. 2 3 minutes would be for 1M rows.. You know how to use visual studio profiling ?

Comment: @shay__ - Thanks for the response! How would I go about awaiting `UpdateStockAsync()` if I can't use `async` in the top `public pgSysproStock()` method? And 2), should I just remove the async from the constructor?

Comment: @DiogoCunha - No sir, I do not know how to use profiling. I will also do some research on it now.

Comment: Btw are you using entity framework to query the database ? Be aware that entity framework perfomance sometimes is far from the desirable. Do the profiling and see what is taking so much time.. Regarding @CareTaker22 comment I don't know if that's a problem, I don't know about wpf but windows forms Ui runs on a separated thread, that way you don't need to wait when you call async methods

Comment: @CareTaker22 I think you misunderstood me.. You **can't** await async methods from within a constructor, so obviously the call to `UpdateStockAsync()`  shouldn't be from inside your constructor. You could decide to make `UpdateStockAsync()` synchronous instead of async, but that would be a mistake. Instead, refactor your code so that `UpdateStockAsync()` will be called from another place, where it can be awaited. That said, your timing issues are not related to your usage of async / await (TMO). I would take @DiodoChuna's advice to measure the time it takes your DB to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your operation is initiating operation incorrectly.
I suggest you create handler  On Load or some other event for your window, mark it async and do the call from there. Should be simple as this:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = false;

    using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var allStock = await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync();

        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = allStock.Select(item =>
                        new AllStock
                        {
                           ...
                        }).ToArray();

        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using Form.Load event but you may use different.